# Python How to change text of already created tab in tkinter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have no idea how to change and access already created ttk.Notebook tab. I don't know how to access specific tab and even "current" doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

app = Tk()

tabs = ttk.Notebook(app)                        # Create Tab Control

options_tab = ttk.Frame(tabs)                   # Create a tab
tabs.add(options_tab, text='Options')           # Add the tab

tabs.pack(expand=1, fill="both")                 # Pack to make visible

lang_dct = {
    "en": 0,
    "af": 1
}

my_lang = lang_dct['en']
print(my_lang)

# New language chosen here
lang_l = Label(options_tab)
lang_l.config(text=["Choose language",
                    "Kies taal"][my_lang])
lang_l.grid(row=0, column=0)


def on_select(event=None):
    print('----------------------------')
    if event: # <-- this works only with bind because `command=` doesn't send event
        print("event.widget:", event.widget.get())

    global my_lang
    cb = event.widget.get()
    if cb == "English":
        my_lang = 0
    elif cb == "Afrikaans":
        my_lang = 1
    print(my_lang)
    change_lang()


def change_lang():
    lang_l.config(text=["Choose language",
                        "Kies taal"][my_lang])
    print(tabs)
    print(tabs.tab("current"))
    tabs.tab("current")['text'] = ["Options",
                                   "Opsies"][my_lang]


language_cb = ttk.Combobox(options_tab, values=("English", "Afrikaans"))
language_cb.grid(row=1, column=0)
language_cb.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', on_select)

app.mainloop()
```

I can print current tab but I can't change it in any way. How can I change text in a ttk tkinter Notepad tab?

Comment: Run the code. you have Options tab at the top I want to change it to other language (Opsies in this case) in the same way as Choose language changes to Kies taal

Comment: Your question would be easier to understand if you didn't have so much code. Since the problem is with changing the text on a tab, all we need is one tab and a small bit of code to make it visible, and then the code to change the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ttk widgets sometimes work a little differently than tk widgets. In the case of notebook tabs, you set the option of a tab with the `tab` method. If you don't provide any arguments other than a tab index, this method will return a dictionary representing the options. Your code is changing the dictionary, changing the dictionary doesn't change the actual widget.

To change an option, give the option name and new value as arguments to the `tab` method. For example:

```
tabs.tab("current", text=["Options", "Opsies"][my_lang])
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yeah I have problem with finding good info in ttk doc. From what I see if I want to change specfic tab I just need to use integer, correct? Here 0 (first tab) works fine.

Comment: @Gunnm: yes, the first argument is what identifies the tab to be configured. You can use an index, the frame that is associated with the tab (eg: `options_tab`), the special index `"current"` or `"end"`, or even an x/y coordinate as a string in the format of  `"@x,y"`